# Cypress - How can I check Google Events fired before the new page loads

Tags: google-analytics, cypress, stub, stubbing

This is the scenario:

- User accesses `index.com`
- Clicks the X button
- A Google Analytic event is fired here **<-- I want to check this event**
- User is redirected to a new page **<-- Events are not longer here**

This is my code:

```
describe("Desktop - Listing details - Google Analytics", () => {
  slugs.forEach((slug, index) => {
    context(`For ${slugs[index]}`, () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        const ga = cy.stub().as("ga");
        cy.on("window:before:load", win => {
          Object.defineProperty(win, "ga", {
            configurable: false,
            get: () => ga, // always return the stub
            set: () => {} // don't allow actual google analytics to overwrite this property
          });
        });
        cy.visit(`/url/a/${slug}/`);
      });

      context("Navigation tab", () => {
        it("Pricing tab", function() {
          cy.get(`[class="nav-links"] > li`)
            .eq(1)
            .click(); // Here a new page loads and the events are not longer present
          cy.get("@ga").should(`be.calledWith`, `send`, {
            hitType: "event",
            eventCategory: "navigation-bar",
            eventAction: "go-to_product_pricing",
            eventLabel: "navigation-tab"
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And a second attempt:

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  // because this is called before any scripts
  // have loaded - the ga function is undefined
  // so we need to create it.
  win.ga = cy.stub().as('ga')
})

describe("Desktop - Listing details - Google Analytics", () => {
  slugs.forEach((slug, index) => {
    context(`For ${slugs[index]}`, () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
             cy.visit(`/url/a/${slug}/`);
      });

      context("Navigation tab", () => {
        it("Pricing tab", function() {
          cy.get(`[class="nav-links"] > li`)
            .eq(1)
            .click(); // Here a new page loads and the events are not longer present
          cy.get("@ga").should(`be.calledWith`, `send`, {
            hitType: "event",
            eventCategory: "navigation-bar",
            eventAction: "go-to_product_pricing",
            eventLabel: "navigation-tab"
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The thing is that Cypress is making the assertion in the New page, and the events I want to check are not longer there.

How can I test this? Honestly, I tried everything.

Comment: searching for the answer to this problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to go into detail, but we achieved something along these lines using intercept https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

In our case, we intercepted a response that contained a redirect url and set it to null so the redirect never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using trigger('click') or ('mousedown') therefore I avoid the actual render of a new page only listen to the events triggered by click/mousedown.